# How do I update the Font that is backinng text style "Title 1" in ios/xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Sort of like CSS, I want to just use my custom font for "Title 1" heading.  I'm not sure how to do this in my storyboard.??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 9, the iOS System Font is "San Francisco" ... previously it was "Helvetica Neue".

All of those Text Styles are based on the System Font, as are the fonts returned by:

```
// Obj-C
UIFont *fnt = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleCaption1];

// Swift
let fnt = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.caption1)
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying there is no way to modify those text styles and I will have to go into every element in my storyboard, and modify it's font?

Comment: Correct, you cannot change those styles... you will either need to change each one in storyboard, subclass and replace your controls, or write some code to change them at runtime.